# hdfs dfs ls not working after multiple nodes configured

Tags: hadoop

I started following an online tutorial to configure multi ndoes on my single local VM. here is the hosts on master node:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
192.168.96.132  hadoop
192.168.96.135  hadoop1
192.168.96.136  hadoop2

ssh:ALL:allow
sshd:ALL:allow
```

Here is the command that used to work:`hdfs dfs -ls`

Now I am seeing error message below:

```
ls: Call From hadoop/192.168.96.132 to hadoop:9000 failed on connection exception: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; 
For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

What is wrong with my configuration? where should I check and correct it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You have to make paswordless-ssh, for that generate ssh key and distribute that to all other nodes

Comment: No, not there yet, it seems I haven't successfully config the network, none of the three nodes in the cluster can ping outside. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
First try to 
ping hadoop,
ping hadoop1 and 
ping hadoop2.
Ex: ping hadoop 
Then just try to connect via ssh
The syntax is 
ssh username@hadoop
ssh username@hadoop1
ssh username@hadoop2
Then see the results to find out whether the systems are connecting or not.
```